# Junk values added at start of exported sql file from teradata

Tags: teradata

im trying to export data from teradata, but the exported files have junk values like () present at the start of every file...
Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem??

```
.Export data file=/DATA/{SQL_DATA}.sql, close
.SET RECORDMODE OFF;
.SET HEADING '';
--.SET FOLDLINE ON ALL;
.SET FORMAT OFF;
.SET LARGEDATAMODE ON;
.SET INDICDATA ON;


Select 
    cast(SQL_FILE as VARCHAR(60000)) 
From 
(database)
.
.
.
```

Comment: These are no *junk values* but the two-byte (word) string length of the VarChar. If it's actually a single column you migth simply switch to REPORT mode, otherwise TPT can easily export CSV, etc.

Comment: You also are requesting null indicator bytes (INDICDATA) in addition to the VARCHAR length bytes.